# is WM_PAINT necessary while implementing winevent in Qt

Tags: c++, windows, qt, message-queue

My Qt Application is to read data from external device, analyse it and then display the results on the screen. As I need to work with GUI, I selected Qt over Winforms. I didn't know that device was only working with windows messages. The device comes with static libs and predefined functions. I am able to access the device from my application (and get the status parameter). the problem comes with windows messages. I need to read buffer from the device and for that device sends BUFFER_FULL message. I have used QWidget::winevent function for that. My implementation looks like following.

in mainWindow.h

```
virtual bool winEvent(MSG *message, long *result);
```

in mainWindow.cpp

```
bool MainWindow::winEvent(MSG *message, long *result)
{
switch(message->message)
{
case BUFFER_DONE:
    qDebug()<<"***---BUFFER_DONE---***";
    return 0;

case WM_PAINT:
    // TODO: set error
    qDebug()<<"***---WM_PAINT---***";
    return 1;

default:
    break;
}
}
```

while debugging the application, it keeps on getting **WM_PAINT** message. I haven't implemented WM_PAINT message. The application has nothing to display and it almost 'pauses' at this point. Without this winevent implementation, it shows me clear widget. I think painting widget would be handled by Qt. Am I right with my understanding or I need to implement WM_PAINT by myself?

Comment: Where is what you paint going to appear?

Comment: I don't paint anything by myself. I use QWidget only to use winevent. Eventually I will just read the buffer and process it in another thread. QWidget has default paint mechanism. I just want to use it.
Also, i think i will use QWidget::paintEvent(). WM_PAINT is window specific message. Right?

Comment: Do you need a widget? Don't you want a message only window?

Comment: I am sorry for my ignorance but I don't understand what you are saying. Only thing that can accept messages in Qt is QWidget, right?

Comment: Is your device library only passing you data via windows messages, or does it also require a window handle to paint on? If it does then there must be an interface function that accepts a HWND of a window you create. If not, then are the interface messages all custom messages (i.e. WM_USER+.....) or do you also receive system messages such as WM_CREATE, WM_PAINT, WM_CLOSE, etc?  Please note that your widget will receive WM_PAINT under windows if it visible but not necessarily from your device. What does the device documentation say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default handling for `WM_PAINT` will be fine. It will do nothing, which is what you want. However, you don't really want a visual control here. What you want, I suspect, is a message only window. That's created by passing `HWND_MESSAGE` to the `hWndParent` of `CreateWindowEx`. I'm not sure if Qt offers such functionality, quite possibly not.

You can carry on using `QWidget` but it does seem a little over-the-top to me. And if you do continue with `QWidget` then you ought at the very least [hide](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#hide) it.

Note that I am assuming that your `winEvent` implementation is correct. You've not shown it all. Specifically you've not shown the code that returns `false` for the messages that you want to receive default handling.

It looks like my assumption was wrong. You were failing to return a value from your `winEvent`. Your compiler will warn about that provided that you enable warnings. You must do this, and then heed the warnings. Your `winEvent` should be:

```
bool MainWindow::winEvent(MSG *message, long *result)
{
    switch(message->message)
    {
    case BUFFER_DONE:
        qDebug()<<"***---BUFFER_DONE---***";
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: please see the edit. I hope I have cleared myself better

Comment: Why are you making the widget visible?

Comment: I am not. that is the default behavior of qt. I must tell you I am not experienced programmer. this is my first Project with qt. so, I may be wrong and that's why I am here to ask for help.

Comment: Call `hide()` on the widget to hide it.

Comment: The problem is not in terms of QWidget is showing. The problem is that program execution halts because it doesn't find implementation for WM_PAINT message. I haven't implemented it because I feel Qt doesn't use it as it is a windows specific message. My question was how can I finish the program execution.

Comment: The default handling of `WM_PAINT` does nothing. I presume that you are returning `false` from your `WinEvent`?

Comment: If you hide() the widget it should not receive WM_PAINT.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, for message only window, Do I always need parent window? Or can I just create a message only window? Do you have a sample for it?

Comment: Message only window you call `CreateWindowEx` passing `HWND_MESSAGE` as `hwndParent`. You still have not shown `winEvent`. Any reason why not?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan you want my winevent implementation? It is there in the question. I have made it more clear this time. WM_PAINT function doesn't have much effect. If I return 1, it will display WM_PAINT in Application Output window constantly. If I return WM_PAINT 0, it will be displayed only once in the Application Output window.

Comment: Your `winEvent` was not in the question. Only part of it. You've added it all now. And it is broken. Probably the root of your problem.

Comment: return false; a single line that cost me three days. now it works as I want. @DavidHeffernan Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: The best advice I can offer is to enable warnings and listen to them. The compiler would have found that immediately.